# Unique views of a Google Doc

Tags: google-docs

A Google Doc was published and I would like to know how many unique viewers have accessed the document.  Ideally, unique anonymous views would tallied each time a unique IP address accesses the doc.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately there is no way currently to see who has viewed a Google Doc.

[On Quora, the CEO of DocSend says](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-see-the-viewing-history-and-chat-history-in-Google-Docs):

> If you’re looking to track views on documents you send, I’d recommend giving [DocSend](https://docsend.com/) a try. DocSend provides live analytics that tell you when your documents are being viewed, and where the viewer is spending time. It also enables you to require that viewers provide their email address name, or company name to help you understand how your document is being shared. DocSend supports Google Docs, PDFs, Word documents, and and many others.

Comment: Please don't just simply link to an outside resource. When this link becomes unavailable this answer is useless. Answers should be self-contained; links should be supplemental.

Comment: Okay, now you've gone to the other extreme and are passing off someone else's words as your own. If you're directly quoting someone else, give them credit. I've tried to edit your answer to do that.

Comment: Sorry but I added his name at the bottom of my answer. I am not looking for any credit. I am just trying to help to gatorback with an advice.